# Theano function with updates produces NAN output

Tags: theano, nan, lasagne

my code looks like.

```
output = lasagne.layers.get_output(output_layer)
loss = function(output) * target
loss = -(loss.sum())

params = lasagne.layers.get_all_params(output_layer)
updates = lasagne.updates.sgd(loss,params,learning_rate=0.00001)

train_fn = theano.function([input,target], loss, updates=updates,allow_input_downcast=True)
validate_fn = theano.function([input,target], loss, allow_input_downcast=True)
```

here outputlayer is a CNN network, and function is defined as follows:

```
def function(X):
    squared_euclidean_distances = (X ** 2).sum(1).reshape((X.shape[0], 1)) + (X ** 2).sum(1).reshape((1, X.shape[0])) - 2 * X.dot(X.T)
    dist =  1/(1+squared_euclidean_distances) 
    Pij = (dist) / (dist.sum(0))    
    return Pij
```

target is a sparse matrix where target(i,j) = 1 if outputlayer(i) and outputlayer(j) belong to the same class, otherwise target(i,j) = 0

When digging the code, I found that the error is from a conv layer in the CNN network, raised by a function *true_div*.

Clearly, the only difference of the train_fn and validate_fn is the updates parameter.
However, I print the output of train_fn and validate_fn with the same dummy input. The output of validate_fn makes sense, but train_fn output is NAN.
I think the ouput is produced before updating updates the parameters. Anything wrong?

Comment: how you compute the loss function?

Comment: thanks, and I have updated the question